# Sending raw ZPL to Zebra printer via PrintServer is not working

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers, zpl, printqueue

**Problem**

I am trying to send zpl RAW to print server. There is a Zebra ZM400 printer. 
I could get PrintServer, PrintQueue objects. Also, I could add a job, and write to its JobStream.

I checked print queue (on Windows), and the document was sent. The printer data light blinks for 1/2 seconds.

**Progress**

Here is my code for print to print server:

```
PrintServer ps = new PrintServer(@"\\192.168.1.1");
PrintQueue pq = ps.GetPrintQueue("Printer 01");

Byte[] myByteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
    @"^XA^MMP^PW300^LS0^LT0^FT10,60^APN,30,30^FH\^FDSAMPLE TEXT^FS^XZ");

PrintSystemJobInfo psji = pq.AddJob();
psji.JobStream.Write(myByteBuffer, 0, myByteBuffer.Length);
psji.JobStream.Flush();
psji.JobStream.Close();
```

**Issue**

When I check print queue (on Windows), the document has 0 bytes. And then, the printer prints nothing.

Do I missing some special char? Or, do I send wrong raw data?

Answer (score 1):

In my application I use the following code which works fine:

```
ZPLString = @"^XA^MMP^PW300^LS0^LT0^FT10,60^APN,30,30^FH\^FDSAMPLE TEXT^FS^XZ";
// Open connection
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
client.Connect("10.10.5.85", 9100);

// Write ZPL String to connection
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
writer.Write(ZPLString);
writer.Flush();

// Close Connection
writer.Close();
client.Close();
```

edit: *port 6101 is the default for Zebra printers, 9100 is the alternate port

Comment: Thank you for your response. In your case, you are connecting directly to the printer. In my case, I need to connect through print server.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I see it now. ZPL looks okay btw. Although you could check if font P is available on the printer. (^APN,30,30)

Comment: I checked and font P is installed in Z:P.FNT. Anyway, when the font is not installed, letters are printed big and pixelated.

Comment: 6101 is actually the default port, 9101 is the alternate port.

Comment: 9100* apologies typo

Answer (score 0):

Combining the OP's question and [Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6007479/johan)'s answer gives you a valid document using [PrintServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printserver?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();

// List the print server's queues
PrintQueue pq = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(@"Boca FGL 200 DPI");
PrintSystemJobInfo job = pq.AddJob();  
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(job.JobStream);
writer.Write(@"hello world<p>");
writer.Flush();
```